# Faster way to loop through every pixel of an image in Python?

Tags: python, image, loops, time, numpy

I need to loop through each pixel of a 2560x2160 2D numpy array (image). A simplified version of my problem is as follows:

```
import time
import numpy as np

t = time.clock()
limit = 9000
for (x,y), pixel in np.ndenumerate(image):
    if( pixel > limit )
        pass
tt = time.clock()
print tt-t
```

This is taking an obnoxious ~30 seconds to complete on my computer. ( Core i7, 8GB ram )
Is there a faster way to perform this loop with an interior 'if' statement? I am only interested in pixels above a certain limit, but I do need their (x,y) indices and value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a boolean matrix:

```
x, y = (image > limit).nonzero()
vals = image[x, y]
```

Comment: WOW! My eyes are opened. Took < 0.1 second.

Comment: what is in x and y here?

Comment: @AndrewHundt: `x` and `y` are arrays of x- and y-indices for the nonzero points, respectively.

Comment: When I run this code with python 2.7, I get an Attribute error saying " 'bool' object has no attribute 'nonzero' ".  What is the portion (image > limit) supposed to do?

Comment: Either one of `image` or `limit` must be a NumPy array - if they are both non-NumPy objects, `image > limit` will probably resolve to a Python boolean instead of a NumPy boolean array.

Answer (score 7):

First, try to use vectorize calculation:

```
i, j = np.where(image > limit)
```

If your problem can't be solve by vectorize calculation, you can speedup the for loop as:

```
for i in xrange(image.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(image.shape[1]):
        pixel = image.item(i, j)
        if pixel > limit:
            pass
```

or:

```
from itertools import product
h, w = image.shape
for pos in product(range(h), range(w)):
    pixel = image.item(pos)
    if pixel > limit:
        pass
```

The numpy.ndenumerate is slow, by using normal for loop and get the value from array by `item` method you can speedup the loop by 4x.

If you need more speed, try to use Cython, it will make your code as fast as C code.