# Python loop through every pixel of image

Tags: python, for-loop

How can I make the below loop(s) faster? It is a pixel by pixel for loop, and when I run it, all I get is a string of the two print statements after the for loop and the if-else block respectively.

```
for i in xrange(0, nCols, 1):
    p = img[i, row] #image[column, row]

    if withinRange(p): #if the pixel is a certain color, or within a certain range of colors
        pixelCount += 1
        #print "count after the initial row loop is: ", pixelCount

print 'time after initial row loop ', time.time()

if pixelCount == 0: # In other words, no pixels were found in this whole row 
                    #- take the average middle row for each line of text
    for i in xrange(0, nCols, 1):
        img[i, row] = 255

else:
    start = row
print 'time after start = row loop', time.time()
```

Does anybody have tips on how I might optimise this?

The `withinRange()` function is a boolean, all it looks at is whether the color intensity (I'm working with grayscale images) is between two specific values, for e.g. if img[x, y] is between 242 and 254, it will be true.

I looked at a couple of answers that seem to be similar, but not quite this. [Faster way to loop through every pixel of an image in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003949/faster-way-to-loop-through-every-pixel-of-an-image-in-python)

I am currently working with scikit image, but I am open to using OpenCV. It is a fairly basic operation of simply checking for certain conditions and then manipulating the value of the pixel intensity.

Comment: Just create a boolean mask and avoid the loop altogether.  `mask = (img >= 242) & (img <= 254)` and then apply to your image.  `img[mask]`

Comment: @gobrewers14 - I don't know if that's possible in this use case. I tried it out, but I am building this so I can find out and extract all the text that has been highlighted with a highlighter from my textbooks.

Comment: @gobrewers14 - I implemented it, but got TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data. Here's the code: `t = time.clock()
limit = 208
filename = 'images/highlight_ocr.png'
img = io.imread(filename)
mask = (img >= 242) & (img <= 254)
vals = img[mask]
viewer = ImageViewer(vals)
viewer.show()
tt = time.clock()
print tt-t`, sorry for some reason I can't seem to make this neat.

Comment: `img[mask]` returns a flattened array of the image where the criteria of the mask is met.  So it looks like you want to find pixels where they are between 242 and 254 and change them to 255?  Then you would do `img[mask] = 255` and it will insert 255 into the spots where that criteria is met.  The error you are getting is from matplotlib, you are trying to plot a flattened array which isn't (at least) 2 dimensional.

Comment: Are you using `numpy`? You probably should.

Comment: JohanL - Yes, @gobrewers - I will try doing that, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @gobrewers14 - how would I go about making the flattened array which isn't 2D, 2D? In other words, how can I see my image in matplotlib.pyplot? It works well otherwise though.