# Boolean Matrix with more than 1 comparison raises error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pixel, boolean-logic

I am trying to find if a pixel's HSV value is within the right threshold, but it's raising an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
x, y = numpy.where(0.08196969696969696 >= img >= 0.1 and 0.7285714285714286 >= img >= 0.525 and 150 >= img >= 95)
```

How do I find all possible pixels within that threshold in the numpy array?

Comment: Wrap the comparisons with () so they have priority, and use `&` and `|` instead of `and` and `or`.

Comment: Test the `where` argument piece by piece.

Comment: @hpaulj I still get the same error if I replace and/or with & and | and add brackets. I also tried to shorten/edit the statement and either it will have the same error or if I make it 1 comparison so -- x, y = numpy.where(0.1 <= img) I am forced to remove the y variable making it -- x = numpy.where(0.1 <= img) otherwise a unpack value error occurs. All im doing is trying to go through every pixel in a picture fast using Boolean matrices.

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = numpy.where(0.08196969696969696 >= img >= 0.1 and 0.7285714285714286 >= img >= 0.525 and 150 >= img >= 95)
```

Focus to the argument, which should produce a n-d boolean array:

```
0.08196969696969696 >= img >= 0.1 and 0.7285714285714286 >= img >= 0.525 and 150 >= img >= 95)
```

() and &:

```
(0.08196969696969696 >= img >= 0.1) & (0.7285714285714286 >= img >= 0.525) & (150 >= img >= 95)
```

The double sided comparison only works for python scalars, not numpy:

```
(0.08196969696969696 >= img) & (img >= 0.1) & (0.7285714285714286 >= img) & (img >= 0.525) & (150 >= img) & (img >= 95)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.3/reference/routines.logic.html

```
np.logical_and.reduce(((0.08196969696969696 >= img), (img >= 0.1), (0.7285714285714286 >= img), (img >= 0.525), (150 >= img), (img >= 95)))
```

But wait, can't we just reduce all those tests down to 2?  What's the shape of `img`?  is it by any chance 3d with a final size 3 dimension?

```
np.logical_and.reduce(((0.08196969696969696 >= img[:,:,0]), (img[:,:,0] >= 0.1), 
(0.7285714285714286 >= img[:,:,1]), (img[:,:,1] >= 0.525), 
(150 >= img[:,:,2]), (img[:,:,2] >= 95)))
```

Or comparing the (n,m,3) `img` with (3,) bounds, with an `all` reduction on the last axis:

```
([0.08196969696969696, 0.7285714285714286, 150] >= img).all(axis=2) & 
([0.1, 0.525, 95] >= img).all(axis=2)
```

Comment: both np.logical_and_reduce() and comparing (n,m,3) with 3 bounds didnt get any pixels when I tested them. I dont exactly know how all of this works but when I tried both codes, I had to use 1 variable - X instead of what I intended which was X, Y. I'm trying to get pixel coordinates of every pixel that matches and I was following code that another stackoverflow post had -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13003956/10620976

Comment: Your link performs just one test on the array, you are trying to perform 6, and combine them in some way.  I can guess what you want, but you need to be clear(er).